# htaccess subdirectory alias for root possible?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I moved a site that used to be at `example.com/en/` to just `example.com`.

however the graphics as still linked to `/en/`.

What do I need to add to my `.htaccess` to make the site serve files under `/en/` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can depend on what directives you already have in your `.htaccess`. However, to *internally rewrite* any request for "images" ie. `/en/<something>/<whatever-image>`. Then you could do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/([^.]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))$ /$1 [L]
```

This allows you to effectively serve image files under both locations, whilst the actual files are outside of `/en/`.

If you want to rewrite *everything* then do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

However, if you've "moved" the site then you probably want to externally "redirect" the page URLs in order to preserve SEO? However, if you are still *linking* to some images using the `/en/` subdirectory then you need to be sure to redirect *pages* only.